# Why is averaging count metric showing different result according to time frames in Datadog?

Tags: datadog

I'm having trouble with configuring defining monitor in Datadog (Or maybe it can be alert in Prometheus, I'm not sure).

I have a metric named `trace.servlet.request.hits`, which is a COUNT metric. Datadog shows me that the interval for this metric is 10 (seconds). I wanted to receive alerts whenever drastic change happens regarding this metric. The metric I defined is `diff(avg:trace.servlet.request.hits{cluster_name:$MY_CLUSTER}.as_count())`.

However, I thought that configuring time frames (https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/guide/custom_time_frames/) would just change the period (or time window), but changing the time frames always show different result for my metric, and thus I'm having hard time how to configure the threshold to get alerts on.

From my understanding, COUNT metric (https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/types/?tab=count#metric-types) is just an addition of all values in one time interval, which I thought that is independent from the time frame. In the case above, one time interval would be 10 seconds.

However, every time I change the time frame, I'm getting different result for the metric. Any help on understanding why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Datadog [aggregates what you are seeing](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/#time-and-space-aggregation) based on the selected interval. You can use the `rollup` method for a bit more control, but there are still [enforced limits](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/rollup/#rollup-interval-enforced-vs-custom) to avoid having more points on the graph than pixels. Longer intervals will always have less granularity.

Comment: Understood! However when setting monitor (and alerts), how would I know how the datapoints would get aggregated?